# Is this action well defined?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

Let $ H $ be a proper subgroup of $ G $ . Then is
\begin{align*}
  \rho :G\times (G:H)& \rightarrow (G:H) \\ 
  (g,hH)& \mapsto ghH 
\end{align*}
a well defined action? This is the left multiplication action and it seems to satisfy all conditions except for the fact that I am not sure that this is even a proper map. Let me elaborate. As $ H $  is not necesseraly normal, coset multiplication is not well defined. Thus if we consider
\begin{align*}
  h_1 H=h_2 H,
\end{align*}
i.e. $ h_1 h_2 ^{-1}\in H $, we need not have
\begin{align*}
  \rho (g,h_1 H)=\rho (g,h_2 H) \tag{\(*\)}
\end{align*}
as
\begin{align*}
  (*)& \iff gh_1 H=gh_2 H \\ 
 &  \iff gh_1 ( gh_2 )^{-1}\in H \\ 
 & \iff  gh_1  h_2 ^{-1} g^{-1} \in H
\end{align*}
need not be true as $ H $  is not neceserally a normal subgroup.

**Main Question: Is the action well defined?**

I would really appreciate if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: Why don't you take some concrete examples of groups and work them out? For instance, look at $S_3$ and one of its non-normal subgroups, and write down this action precisely. I am sure you can get some insights into your question.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I tried playing around with S3 but to no avail. The reason I am asking this question is because whilst investigating the kernel of the homomorphism of the action (that is the homomorphism between $G$ and $Sym(G:H)$), I get that the kernel is H, which simply can not be true as H needs not be a normal subgroup.

Comment: You have the condition for equality of left cosets wrong. $xH=yH$ if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$; you have $xy^{-1}\in H$, which is the condition for equality of *right* cosets,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You messed up the condition for equality of left cosets.

Recall that $xH=yH$ if and only if $y^{-1}xH=H$, if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$.

So if $xH=yH$ and $g\in G$, then $y^{-1}x\in H$, hence $y^{-1}(g^{-1}g)x\in H$, hence $(y^{-1}g^{-1})(gx)\in H$, hence $(gy)^{-1}(gx)\in H$, hence $gxH = gyH$. So the action is well defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The misconception really hindered my understanding.